# Convert Excel VBA to C++Builder OLE API

Tags: vba, c++builder, ole

how to convert the following VBA code to c++ builder in OLE? Thanks.

```
Range("A10:B28").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$10:$B$28")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("test1").IncrementLeft -288.5293700787
ActiveSheet.Shapes("test1").IncrementTop -39.7059055118
```

I have tried the following code, the c++ builder crash at last line

```
#include <excel_2k.h>

outXL = Variant::CreateObject("excel.application");
outXL.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);
outWorkbooks = outXL.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks");
outWorkbook = outWorkbooks.OleFunction("Open", "D:\\test.xls");
outWorkSheets = outWorkbook.OlePropertyGet("Worksheets");
outActiveSheet = outWorkbook.OlePropertyGet("Worksheets", 0);
outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Activate");


Range=outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Range",
        outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Cells",5,1),
        outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Cells",20,2));
Chart = outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Shapes").OleFunction("AddChart2");

//=========This line Dump ERROR=========
Chart.OlePropertySet("ChartType",xlXYScatter);
```

Comment: Crashes in what way exactly? What is the actual error message?

Comment: In your VBA, `AddChart2()` has two arguments, `240` and `xlXYScatter`. In your C++, your call to `AddChart2()` has only one argument, the `xlXYScatter`. Maybe something there?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Perhaps, but I don't know how to modify the code, the OLE resource is not enough on the internet...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Show Eolesyserror Undeclared Identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, please reference the following code...

```
Chart = outXL.OlePropertyGet("Charts").OleFunction("Add");
Chart.OlePropertySet("ChartType", xlXYScatter);
Range=outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Range",
    outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Cells",iDrawRowFrom,iDrawColFrom),
    outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Cells",iDrawRowTo,iDrawColTo));

Chart.OleProcedure("SetSourceData", Range);
Chart.OleFunction("Location", 2, strOutSheetName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

IDK, if this is the answer, but ISTM you need to modify the code here

```
Chart = outActiveSheet.OlePropertyGet("Shapes").OleFunction("AddChart2", 240, xlXYScatter);
```

That is the way it is called in the VBA. You just have OleFunction("AddChart2")

What is the value of Chart after the function call?